# How do I create an "increment" function that takes an integer pointer and increases its value?

Tags: pointers, rust

In [this](http://aml3.github.io/RustTutorial/html/02.html) tutorial, the following code is given:

```
fn increment(r: &mut int) {
    *r = *r + 1;
}

fn main () {
    let mut x = ~10;
    increment(x);
}
```

I know that this syntax is obsolete, so I ported the code by myself:

```
fn increment(r: &mut i32) {
    *r = *r + 1;
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = Box::new(10);
    increment(x);
}
```

When I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:8:15
  |
8 |     increment(x);
  |               ^ expected &mut i32, found struct `std::boxed::Box`
  |
  = note: expected type `&mut i32`
             found type `std::boxed::Box<{integer}>`
```

I tried a lot of combinations with ampersands, `mut`s and so on. What is the right way to make such function?

Comment: `increment(&mut *x);` Taking a mutable reference to the dereference of x.

Comment: If x is already mutable, why I have to use the mut keyword again?

Comment: Because it's possible to take an immutable or mutable reference to a mutable variable, and you have to specify which one you want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, your tutorial is horribly obsolete. There is a great [official book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/README.html).

Second, you shouldn't use boxes unless you really have to. That is, don't write this:

```
let mut x = Box::new(10);
```

write this:

```
let mut x = 10;
```

unless you *really* know why you need `Box<i32>`. In short, boxes are needed for three things: recursive types, trait objects and passing around **very** large structs.

Third, yes, as A.B. said, you need to use a `&mut` reference:

```
let mut x = 10;
increment(&mut x);
```

There is no need to dereference here because `x` is no longer a `Box`, it is just a regular value.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to get an `add_one()` function working on a `Box<i32>` and finally got it to work as in this example:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = Box::new(5);

    println!("{:?}", x);
    println!("{:?}", *x);

    //  Taking a mutable reference to the dereference of x.
    add_one(&mut *x);

    println!("{:?}", x);

    boxed_add_one(&mut x);

    println!("{:?}", x);

}

// Gets a reference to a mutable int
fn add_one(num: &mut i32) {
    *num += 1;
}

// Gets a reference to a mutable box with int
fn boxed_add_one(b: &mut Box<i32>) {
    let ref mut num = **b;
    *num += 1;
}
```